# Facebook comments regex matching

Tags: python, regex, facebook

I'm a grad student doing some research with some public facebook comments on a company wall. I'm only interested in frequency, not the text of the comments.

So I'm looking at doing a regular expression to match what I need, but I'm not very good at regex yet.  (Also, I only have comments in text format, not html - they're all in a text file.)

This means I need to parse the last line of each comment. I use the following regular expression:

```
(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December \d+ at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(Yesterday at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(\d+ hours ago)|(About an hour ago) \D*?(\d+)
```

Some samples:

```
September 5 at 8:40pm · Like · 23
Yesterday at 5:35am · Like 
10 hours ago · Like · 2
6 hours ago · Like
```

I expect to get:

Group 1: either: [Month] [day] OR Yesterday at :am/pm 
                 OR # hours ago
Group 2: # of likes

Code in Python (sorry if it's not super Python-esque):

```
import re
for line in open('comments.txt','r'):
     strPat = '(January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December \d+ at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(Yesterday at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(\d+ hours ago)|(About an hour ago) \D*?(\d+)'
     pat1 = re.compile(strPat, line)
     m = re.match(pat1, line)
     if m:
          print m.group(1), m.group(2)
```

Some sample output:

```
September 5 at 8:40pm None
None None
```

First, it's not capturing the '8 hours ago' portion. Second, it seems that it's not capturing the number of likes for any cases. I'm sure there's something wonky about my regex pattern.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OR operators `|` are not working like you expect it's working.

A simple instance of this is:

```
(\d+ hours ago)|(About an hour ago) \D*?(\d+)
```

This will match either: `(\d+ hours ago)` OR `(About an hour ago) \D*?(\d+)` and not `(\d+ hours ago) \D*?(\d+)` OR `(About an hour ago) \D*?(\d+)`

You thus need to group them, here in a non-capturing group:

```
(?:(\d+ hours ago)|(About an hour ago)) \D*?(\d+)
```

Applying this principle to the regex where applicable, you get some better results.

Next, since you have several lines, I would advise using the anchors and multiline flags together:

```
strPat = r'^(?:((?:January|February|March|April|May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December) \d+ at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(Yesterday at \d+:\d+[ap]m)|(\d+ hours ago)|(About an hour ago)) \D*?(\d+)?$'
m = re.match(pat1, line, re.M)
```

You will notice I also put a `?` after the last capture, which is to handle cases where there are no likes.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/hZ2gQ3).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thanks for explaining for that for me. I confess I didn't really understand the grouping before.